# Android Studio spamming "I/SurfaceView: ..." messages to console when running app through USB phone

Tags: android, console, emulation, device, spam

Sorry for the vague title. When I run my application on an emulator device, in this case Nexus 5x (Android 8.1, API 27), everything is fine. However when running the application on a real device through USB, the device being Xperia XA1 Ultra (Android 7.0, API 24), the console output window gets spammed with this:

```
I/SurfaceView: Punch a hole(dispatchDraw), this = com.example.xlog.fighter.GamePanel{d2bce30 VFE...... ......I. 0,0-1776,1080}
I/SurfaceView: 155302755 Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@9a72360
I/SurfaceView: 155302755 Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@5318019
```

I don't know in which order these three lines are being outputted.

My app is using a SurfaceView to draw on. The app works fine and behaves the same on the emulator and on the physical device. Why are these messages being spammed like this when running on a physical device? I can't even debug with prints while this is going on.

The spammed lines are outputted in the Run window. I can fold them so it becomes a little less annoying but the point is why is this happening?

Comment: You can filter what message you want to see in logcat. All the message you are getting is All event your Phone is running

Comment: This is in the Run window, not logcat. I did fold it though, although it still is annoying, as now the window is spammed with "<x internal calls>". I can easily spot my debug prints now though. But, my question was why is this happening when I run it on the physical device but not the emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old post but I had same issue on same phone and I found a solution. Hope this helps someone.

Anyway, according to [SurfaceView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView):

> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its
>   SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its
>   surface to be displayed.

So, if you set `setZOrderOnTop(true);` in your custom surface view init that annoying message flood disappears.